Could the energy or more clearly energy transfer to a object be thought as force packets applied to it, like instances of force?
then in this way we take energy transfer as force over distance to kind of map or use  scale forces instances applied over a particular distance as energy transfer, as if a force applied to object over 1m , vs force applied over 2meters then force packets combined or energy transfer will be double in 2m case vs 1m and for this case why is energy transfer not force applied over time or why only force integral over distance but not with time.

it's unclear (at least to me) what you are asking.

If you consider the transfer of energy packets instead, then you are onto something. Photons are packets of light energy that transfer energy from one thing to another.


could the energy or more clearly energy transfer to a object be thought as force packets applied to it, like instances of force

No. Force is a transfer of momentum, not energy. So $\vec F=d\vec p/dt$.
You can have forces without any energy transfer. Note that force is a vector and energy is not, so the incompatibility should be clear.
The quantity that represents the mechanical energy transfer is the mechanical power $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v = dE/dt$ which is not a vector.

if we only consider cases where force applied cause enegy transfer like pushing a object from rest to motion using force applied in 1 direction.

even in such cases force is still a vector and energy is not. Force is a transfer of momentum. Momentum and energy are different things. If you confuse them you will run into problems, and if you deliberately try to confuse them then you will deliberately run into problems
